# MooTools Event Delegation using HTML5 data attributes

Tags: javascript, mootools, event-delegation

Is it possible to have event delegation using the HTML5 data attributes in MooTools?

The HTML structure I have is:

```
​<div id="parent">
    <div>not selectable</div>
    <div data-selectable="true">selectable</div>
    <div>not selectable either.</div>
    <div data-selectable="true">also selectable</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And I want to setup `<div id="parent">` to listen to all clicks **only** on child elements that have the `data-selected` attribute.

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong:

The events are being setup as:

```
$("parent").addEvent("click:relay([data-selectable])", function(event, el) {
    alert(this.get('text'));
});
```

but the click callback is fired on clicking all div's, not just the ones with a data-selectable attribute defined. You can see this example on http://jsfiddle.net/NUGD4/

A workaround is to adding this as a CSS class, which works with delegation but I would prefer to be able to use data-attributes as it's used throughout the application.

Comment: The thing is that the current selector engine in MooTools wouldn't even return the correct element when doing `$$('div[data-selectable]')`. There is no way around it without making some fundamental alterations to the selector engine.

Comment: Now, what you can do is use the future selector engine (from 1.3) with the 1.2 release, just follow these instructions: http://gist.github.com/361474

Comment: thanks for the link @Oskar.. it works perfectly! is Slick going to replace the existing selector engine in 1.3?

Comment: could you add this comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: yes, in fact 1.3 release will feature Slick as the selector engine - we're all pretty excited about this, since Slick is a masterpiece!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use the future selector engine (from 1.3) with the 1.2 release, just follow these instructions: gist.github.com/361474

Answer (score 2):

Mootools does not accept "-" in attribute name. I consider, it's bug. Use undersore:

```
data_selectable="true"
```

Comment: Replacing the dash with an underscore wouldn't make it HTML5 anymore, now would it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MooTools 1.3, the code below works just fine as seen in this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LHZHY/)

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>not selectable</div>
    <div data-selectable="true">selectable</div>
    <div>not selectable either</div>
    <div data-selectable="true">also selectable</div>
</div>

$("parent").addEvent("click:relay([data-selectable])", function(ev, el) {
    this.highlight();
});
```